# Show div on the same page and apply opacity to background

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make my whole body tag only to be blurred by using opacity. This should run only when I clicked on a button. My button function as a trigger to show a div. But when I do, all of it becomes blurry.

```
theButton.onclick = function() { 
    document.getElementById('show-form').style.visibility='visible'; 
    document.getElementById('body').style.opacity='0.5'  
}
```

Comment: what do you expect to happen instead? What do you mean by "**all of it** becomes blurry" ?

Comment: Opacity also affects the child objects, if this is your problem. Set the alpha of the background color instead

Comment: @NickParsons What I mean is everything inside my body tag gets affected by the opacity. What I want is an exemption, a div that is inside my body tag, yet it will not become opaque.

Comment: @Bálint yes sir, it affects all the child objects, is there a way I can exclude a div to be opaque?

Comment: I gave you the solution in the comment: use an rgba background, not opacity

Answer (score 0):

I think you can apply the opacity only in the body background instead of the whole body element. Try the below code.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

const invisible = document.querySelector('#show-form');

function showVisible() {
  invisible.style.visibility = 'visible';
  document.body.classList.add('with-opacity');
}

btn.addEventListener('click', showVisible);
```

```css
#show-form {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 70px;
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.with-opacity {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="show-form">Hello World!</div>
<br><br>
<button>Click me</button>
```